Lua: Missing argument in inventoryEvent.OnServerEvent
I get the error from the title in my Roblox(Lua) code. Here's the code:
local inventoryEvent = game.ReplicatedStorage.Remotes.InventoryEvent

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    -- Ensure the player's inventory exists
    local inventory = player:FindFirstChild("Inventory")
    if not inventory then
        inventory = Instance.new("Folder")
        inventory.Name = "Inventory"
        inventory.Parent = player
    end

    -- Ensure InventoryGui and its components exist
    local inventoryGui = player.PlayerGui:WaitForChild("InventoryGui")
    local inventoryFrame = inventoryGui:WaitForChild("InventoryFrame")
    local itemsFrame = inventoryFrame:WaitForChild("ItemsFrame")

    -- Connect inventory child added event
    inventory.ChildAdded:Connect(function(Item)
        print("Item added to inventory: " .. Item.Name)  -- Debugging statement
        inventoryEvent:FireClient(player, Item.Name, true)  -- Pass the item's name as a string and true as Value
    end)
end)

inventoryEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, ItemName, Value, button)
        -- Validate arguments
    if not (player and ItemName and Value and button) then
        warn("Missing argument in inventoryEvent.OnServerEvent")
        return
    end

    -- Debugging output
    print("Received request to process item:", ItemName)

    if Value == false then
        local selectedItem = player.Inventory:FindFirstChild(ItemName)
        if not selectedItem then
            print("Items in inventory:")
            for _, item in ipairs(player.Inventory:GetChildren()) do
                print(item.Name)
            end
            warn("Selected item not found in inventory: " .. ItemName)
            return
        end

        local backpack = player.Backpack:GetChildren()
        local characterItems = player.Character:GetChildren()

        if #backpack == 0 and not player.Character:FindFirstChildWhichIsA("Tool") then
            button.Text = "Unequip"
            button.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(1, 0, 0)
            selectedItem:Clone().Parent = player.Backpack
        else
            for _, v in ipairs(backpack) do
                button.Text = "Equip"
                button.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(0, 1, 0)
                v:Destroy()
            end
            for _, v in ipairs(characterItems) do
                if v:IsA("Tool") then
                    button.Text = "Equip"
                    button.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(0, 1, 0)
                    v:Destroy()
                end
            end
        end
    end
end)


And the real error: Missing argument in inventoryEvent.OnServerEvent  -  Server - InventoryScript:27
Can anyone help?
I tried asking chat gpt, copilot and every possible lua guide to fix it!

Are you sure you did not mixed up events, and if not, where is FireServer? https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/RemoteEvent#OnServerEvent

don't you think it would be nice if you'd format your post properly? you must have realized that it's looking aweful and yet you decided to leave it as is.

"Your" code is creating this error message you complain about:
if not (player and ItemName and Value and button) then
  warn("Missing argument in inventoryEvent.OnServerEvent")      <--- here
  return
end

print the arguments' values to find out which one is missing and fix that.
